# Time incorrect after suspending

Tags: time, clock, timezone

Before I close the lid of the Ubuntu 23.04 laptop, for example the time is 12:34. When I open the lid, the time becomes `X` hours faster than the correct time.

My timezone is `UTC+X` and I ran `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1` to prevent dual boot issues with Windows.

So how to fix this issue, thanks in advance for any help given.

Btw, can I reset `timedatectl`? I probably ran a few commands in the past but forgot/unaware of, starting from scratch may help resolve the issue easier but I can't seem to find anything online.

Comment: Try sudo hwclock --systohc and sudo timedatectl set-ntp true